# How to install customized openssh on FreeBSD?

Tags: freebsd, openssh

i am new in unix/freebsd. my boss asked me for customizing openssh authentication method. i should create a "Master Password" for all users who want to login as root. if they have the Master Password, they can log in as root, else ever they should have root password. i downloaded the openssh source code and made some changes over there. whether or not the customized version works well, i need to build and install my version on FreeBSD 9.2 but there is two problem:

1) i do not know how to remove pre installed  version of openssh. after 2h searching, i could not found a way to properly remove that.

2) how do i install the customized version?

OS: FreeBSD 9.2.

Comment: I recommend you take a look at sudo instead. Allowing root-access from remote has become a bad practice due to all the security implications it causes. Using sudo each user logs in with it's own credentials and then issue the sudo command to perform their duties.

Comment: @kometen , thanks for your answer. i know about security implications but i have to do it.

Comment: Allowing root-access from remote does not require modifying openssh, it's a  configuration change. But sudo fits the bill much better. By modifying this vital part upgrading from FreeBSD 9.2 to a later version becomes very cumbersome. So it appears your boss knows to little about sysadmin in general. And it's much easier to revoke access from users not working there any longer.

Comment: This tells you the pkg commands used in the old and new version of FreeBSD: https://wiki.freebsd.org/PkgPrimer It should be just a matter of deleting the old package and installing a new one.

Comment: @Amiramix OpenSSH is also part of the base system in FreeBSD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove openssh from the base system, what you could try is this (you need to have the OS source installed);

Add `WITHOUT_OPENSSH=true` to `/etc/src.conf`.

Then go to `/usr/src`,  and run `make check-old` as `root`. That should list the files from openssh. If that checks out OK, run `make -DBATCH_DELETE_OLD_FILES delete-old` as `root`.